# При попытке вставить плеер yohoho в react ничего не происходит

Tags: reactjs, видео, mediaplayer

```
<div id="yohoho" data-title="Тайна Коко"></div>
<script src="//yohoho.cc/yo.js"></script>
```

Вот, что предалгают сделать.

Если вставить это в обычный `html`, то все работает. Но при попытке взаимодействовать с плеером через `React`, ничего не происходит. Попытался подключить скрипт как в самом `index.html`, так и в компоненте.
Что я пытаюсь :

````
  return (
    <div className="collection-container">
      <div className="video">
        <div id="yohoho" data-title="Тайна Коко"></div>
        <script src="//yohoho.cc/yo.js"></script>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};```

Как быть?
````

Answer (score 0):

тег script не рендерится в компоненте, его нужно добавлять в дом вручную

```
    useEffect(() => {
  const script = document.createElement('script')
  script.src = "https://yohoho.cc/yo.js"
  document.body.appendChild(script)
  return () => { document.body.removeChild(script) }
}, [])
```

Через хук добавить в каком-либо компоненте и все заработает, остается только вставить

```
<div id="yohoho" data-title="Тайна Коко"></div>
```

в нужном месте